# Launch Configuration or Launch Template for autoscaling group

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am using `CapacityProvider` and `AutoScaling`
`This makes the`Launch Configuration`, I don't

```
const autoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ASG', {
  vpc,
  securityGroup:instanceSg,
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.medium'),
  machineImage: ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux(),
  autoScalingGroupName:`myapp-${targetEnv}-asg`,
  keyName:"ssh-test",
  minCapacity:1,
  maxCapacity:3
});
const capacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'AsgCapacityProvider', {
  autoScalingGroup,

  capacityProviderName: `myapp-${targetEnv}-cp`
});

cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider);
```

honestly saying , I am not sure where `launch configuration` is created, but after deployment, there is one `launch configuration`.(maybe in `AutoScalingGroup()`?)

However in aws launch configuration console,

There is message such as

```
Recommendation to not use launch configurations
Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling no longer adds support for new EC2 features to launch configurations and will stop supporting new EC2 instances types after December 31, 2022. We recommend that customers using launch configurations migrate to launch templates. For more information, see the documentation
```

So, I want to change `launch configuration` to `launch template`